# CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format

Tags: php, mysql, yii

im using yii framework and mysql. i got an error "CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement:

> SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '' for column 'updated' at row 1.

The SQL statement executed was:

> INSERT INTO `posmodel` (`brandid`, `name`, `active`, `created`, `updated`, `editedbyid`, `forapproval`, `approvedbyid`) VALUES (:yp0, :yp1, 1, NOW(), :yp2, :yp3, :yp4, :yp5)"

when im trying to add a record into the database. can someone help me in my problem. i immediately need to fix it. thanks.

Comment: So what's the datetime vale you're trying to insert? the query itself looks ok, but obviously you're trying to stuff something into the `updated` field that mysql doesn't like.

Comment: the datetime value would be like this 0000-00-00 00:00:00. what should i do? please help me. thanks.

Comment: what is the value of :yp2 for updated column.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways:

1. set :yp2 as NOW()
2. use next behavior at model:

   ```
   public function behaviors(){
      return array(
       'CTimestampBehavior' => array(
           'class' => 'zii.behaviors.CTimestampBehavior',
           'createAttribute' => 'created',
           'updateAttribute' => 'updated',
       ));
   }
   ```